# lanterna.InputProvider.pollInput() crashes the application on launch while readInput() does not and works as expected

Tags: java, lanterna

I am using lanterna to build a front end for my application and it requires a non-blocking input method so the displayed data can continuously refresh.

for some reason the method for non-blocking input (pollInput) crashes on calling while the blocking method of the same class (readInput) works as intended

https://github.com/CaderHancock/options

```
                while(itsPartyTime)
                {       try
                        {        
                                 keyStroke = screen.pollInput();
                                textGraphics.putString(15,15, keyStroke.toString() );
                        }catch(Exception e){
                                textGraphics.putString(15,15, e.getMessage());
                        }
```

the above crashes

if the method readInput() is used instead everything works

Answer (score 0):

screen.pollInput() will return null and continue on

So in your loop, most of the time it will be null, which is expected.